# h2o Cluster total memory unexpectedly low

Tags: java, r, h2o

I'm working on a remote server with 196 GB of ram but when I use h2o.init(nthreads = -1) it says that the total cluster memory is .96 GB. Furthermore, when I try to use max_mem_size = "2g" I get an error saying that the JVM could not be created.

Now, the server is using a 32 bit Java version and I do not have admin access. What do I need to do to get more cluster memory?

Thanks

Comment: I think your `1` got converted to a `.` by accident. Happens all the time :)

Comment: haha you're funny. silly R

Answer (score 1):

> Now, the server is using a 32 bit Java version and I do not have admin access. What do I need to do to get more cluster memory?

This is the problem. 32-bit processes can't allocate more than 4 GB of RAM. So your 196 GB server effectively rendered useless with 32 bit JVM. Update to 64-bit JVM and it would solve it.